# Detecting validation errors using PRISM4

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-4

I'm doing an app using Prism 4 and WPF and I've some inputs validations and it works as expected but when the user clicks a button I need to know in that moment whether there are validation errors presents.

Does Prism4 have something implemented to handle this or I've to implement it by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with validation errors isn't something Prism provides as a part of the library. What prism does provide that can be useful when implementing validation is the [`IConfirmNavigationRequest` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.iconfirmnavigationrequest_members%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx), which enables you to stop navigation in certain cases - for example when the page did not pass validation.

To implement validation in your application, I recommend using the [`IDataErrorInfo` interface](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/) (or `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in .NET 4.5/Silverlight).

**EDIT**

To know whether your view passed validation, you'll need to expose an `IsValid` property in your viewmodel that will return this information. One way to do so is to examine the viewmodel and return this data; another way is to have your `ViewBase` register to its errors event using `Validation.AddErrorHandler`, and call `ViewModelBase.AddError()`/`ViewModelBase.RemoveError()` on your view-model. This way your view-model knows about the validation errors and can easily return whether the view is valid or not.

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing IDataErrorInfo in my model but I've a Window with some TextBoxes that I'm validating. Now when the user click the "Save" button I need to be sure that there're no validation errors currently to proceed to save the text in the TextBoxes.

Comment: Hi @Lester I will use the second way but I don't know how to call AddError() and RemoveError() from my Model. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Michelle You'll have to implement these methods yourself, probably in your viewmodel base class. Simplest way is to just keep a collection of errors and update it as necessary when those methods are called. Then the implementation of `IsValid` would be as simple as `return _myErrorCollection.Count == 0;`